# Random peaks in JMH Benchmark Iterations

Tags: java, garbage-collection, microbenchmark, jmh

I am trying to bench a very fast method (~20 us/op), and it seems to work pretty well, excepted for a few iterations which are **randomly very long**:

```
Iteration  63: 14.319 us/op
Iteration  64: 13.128 us/op
Iteration  65: 15.198 us/op
Iteration  66: 20.822 us/op
Iteration  67: 21.669 us/op
Iteration  68: 21.439 us/op
Iteration  69: 15.946 us/op
Iteration  70: 18.793 us/op
Iteration  71: 19.212 us/op
Iteration  72: 816.129 us/op  // oopsy
Iteration  73: 22.115 us/op
Iteration  74: 15.143 us/op
Iteration  75: 18.423 us/op
Iteration  76: 15.238 us/op

Result "benchmark.StuffBench.run_bench":
  20.629 ±(99.9%) 9.164 us/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (12.689, 20.629, 816.129), stdev = 47.763
  CI (99.9%): [11.464, 29.793] (assumes normal distribution)
```

It might be the GC, but `shouldDoGc(false)` does not change anything:

```
final Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(StuffBench.class.getSimpleName())
                .shouldDoGC(false)
                .build();
Collection<RunResult> runResults = new Runner(options).run();
```

Benchmark class:

```
@Fork(value = 2)
@Threads(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 1000, time = 50, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 150, time = 50, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Timeout(time = 50, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StuffBench {
    private Stuff stuff;

    @Setup
    public void initialize() {
        stuff = new Stuff();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void run_bench() {
        stuff.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this kind problem I have used what I call a jitter sampler. You have one thread setting a timestamp, running the code, reset the timestamp and pausing to not overload the CPU. A second thread samples the time stamp and if it is active and has been too long e.g. 20 us, you print a stack trace of what it is doing. e.g. Thread.getStackTrace()  Combine the most common stack traces and you have a safepoint which can point to the problem (or the first safepoint after the problem) It's a bit more art than science ;)

Comment: Thanks @Peter, it's a bit abstract for me, but it you are using a timestamp to measure performances, I assume you don't use JMH? 

Or is it only a temporary method to find out the reason of the peaks?

Comment: @Pleymor it's a simple harness for find the cause of the peaks. I use `System.nanoTime()` assigned to a `volatile long` field.